# cross link products in woocommerce "both ways"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Is there an option with WooCommerceto link a product "both ways", where if I select that CD XXX is related to CD YYY, when I view product CD XXX it will show a related product as CD YYY, and if I view CD YYY it will show related product of CD XXX simultaneously?

Seems this is not standard inside WooCommerce, and if I am correct I would need to come up with a solution that does this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [related products](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/related-products-up-sells-and-cross-sells/#section-3)

Comment: please correct me if i am wrong: but related products do not related "both ways", as my entire point: if I have a product CD XXX and i say it relates to CD YYY, if you go and view cd YYY you will not see CD XXX as a related. related products only work "one way", i.e, CD XXX will relate to CD YYY in a "one way" relationship

Comment: No it won't go both ways by default, you would need to add related products to both CD XXX and CD YYY: On product CD XXX you would add CD YYY as a related product and then on CD YYY you would add CD XXX as a related product.

Comment: yes that is the entire point of this post. i am seeking a solution "both ways"  - the method you propose would take years if client has millions of products